# GSUB doesnt works without spaces

Tags: lua

I was trying to make a simple text cryptor, but the script works only if put spaces after every symbol

code:

```
local text = ""

local tdext = text:gsub("%S+", {["+"] = "a", ["×"] = "b", ["÷"] = "c", ["="] = "d", ["/"] = "e", ["_"] = "f", ["€"] = "g", ["¥"] = "h", ["₩"] = "i", ["!"] = "j", ["@"] = "k", ["#"] = "l", ["$"] = "m", ["%"] = "n", ["^"] = "o", ["&"] = "p", ["*"] = "q", ["("] = "r", [")"] = "s", ["-"] = "t", ["'"] = "u", [":"] = "v", [";"] = "w", [","] = "x", ["?"] = "y", ["."] = "z", [" "] = " "})

print(tdext)
```

I tried fixing it, but it doesnt do what it should.
If i put in text variable "÷ =" it outputs "b c", but if i am putting "÷=" in variable it will output "÷=".

Comment: The standard `gsub` function works on single-byte characters. Your example uses multi-byte characters, probably from UTF.

Comment: Replace `"%S+"` with `".[\128-\191]*"`

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a closer look at your substitutions:

```lua
local subs = {
    ["+"] = "a", ["×"] = "b", ["÷"] = "c", ["="] = "d", ["/"] = "e",
    ["_"] = "f", ["€"] = "g", ["¥"] = "h", ["₩"] = "i", ["!"] = "j",
    ["@"] = "k", ["#"] = "l", ["$"] = "m", ["%"] = "n", ["^"] = "o",
    ["&"] = "p", ["*"] = "q", ["("] = "r", [")"] = "s", ["-"] = "t",
    ["'"] = "u", [":"] = "v", [";"] = "w", [","] = "x", ["?"] = "y",
    ["."] = "z", [" "] = " "
}
local tdext = text:gsub("%S+", subs)
```

`%S+` matches a *sequence* of one or more non-space *bytes*. If you have single characters - multi-byte (UTF-8) or single-byte (ASCII) - this will work fine. However if you have a sequence of multiple characters (say, `+-`), this won't perform the replacement, since both `+` and `-` won't be found in your lookup table. The same is the case for the multi-byte `÷=`: `÷ =` works, because your characters are separated by spaces; `÷=` doesn't, because the pattern greedily matches the sequence.

If this is supposed to be a character-wise substitution, you'll need to match characters (UTF-8 sequences, which includes ASCII). Lua 5.3 and later will have the "constant" [`utf8.charpattern`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.charpattern) which is a pattern string matching a single UTF-8 character. If you have a recent Lua version, the fix becomes trivial: Just replace `"%S+"` with `utf8.charpattern`:

```lua
local tdext = text:gsub(utf8.charpattern, subs)
```

In older Lua versions (up to and including 5.2), you'll have to write this pattern yourself, using decimal escapes:

```lua
local charpattern = "[%z-\127\194-\244][\128-\191]*"
local tdext = text:gsub(charpattern, subs)
```

Alternatively, if you also want to support multi-character substitutions, you can simply apply the substitutions one by one (which is however significantly less efficient by a factor linear in the number of entries in the `subs` table):

```lua
-- We need to escape everything to make Lua treat it as a literal string
local function escape_pattern(str)
    return str:gsub(".", "%%.")
end

local tdext = text
for from, to in pairs(subs) do
    tdext = tdext:gsub(escape_pattern(from), escape_pattern(to))
end
```